# Symfony 6 & webpack encore : how use a .env variable from scss files?

Tags: symfony, webpack, sass, webpack-encore

I make a webapp with the framework Symfony (version 6) and I use a common value from my js and scss files. In the futurs, I would like change easly this value, so I set the value in a global variable in the .env file.

Next, I tried to modify my `webpack.config.js` file for pass the value of the global variable. I guess I must modify the line `.enableSassLoader()`, but I don't find a doc for show how do that...

How can I pass a variable to my scss ?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

The (very simple) answers :)

In the `webpack.config.js` file :

```js
let dotenv = require('dotenv');

const env = dotenv.config();
if (env.error) {
    throw env.error;
}
const foo = env.parsed.foo;

// ...

Encore

// ...

  .enableSassLoader((options)=>{
    options.additionalData = `$faa:${foo};` 
    // don't forget the ;
    // now, the var 'faa' can be used in scss files
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The env vars stored in the root `.env` file are already [accessible through Node](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs/) and can be used directly at `process.env.ENV_VAR`.

For instance in `webpack.config.js`:

```js
// Encore config
Encore
  .enableSassLoader((options)=>{
    options.additionalData = process.env.ENV_VAR;
  })
```

It is also possible to load specific `.env.xyz` env files using [Dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

```js
// Option 1 => loading local env vars from .env.local
require('dotenv').config({path: '.env.local'})

// Option 2 => loading dev env vars from .env.dev
if (Encore.isDev()) {
    require('dotenv').config({path: '.env.dev'})
}

// Alternatively, option 3 => loading current env vars from .env.{XYZ}
if (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  require('dotenv').config({path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`})
}

// Encore config
Encore
  .enableSassLoader((options)=>{
    options.additionalData = process.env.ENV_VAR;
  })
```